# Identify duplicated payments

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have payment table as follows:

> id              int(11)
>
> customer_id   int(11)
>
> period_type     varchar(255)
>
> state       varchar(255)
>
> starts_on   date
>
> ends_on         date
>
> refund_id   int(11)

each customer has a different payments period as follows

> period_type
>   =('Monthly','FourWeekly','Weekly','Annually','Fortnightly','BiAnnually','Quarterly')
>   starts_on is the beginning of the period and ends_on id the end of the
>   period.

I should be able to identify duplicated payments in order to refund the amount and then delete the duplicated one.
A payment is duplicated when there are other payments covering the same pay period or part of the pay period and not in `state='refunded'`.

**Examples**:

customer A has 2 payment from(starts_on= 1 Jan) to (ends_on 31 Jan), both in state='nvested' those payments should be selected as duplicated

customer B has 2 payment from 1 Jan to 31 Jan, one in state='refunded' and the other with state='invested', those payments shouldn't be selected.

customer C has 2 payment, one from 1 Jan to 31 Jan and the other from 6th Jan to 5th Feb, both in state='invested' those payments should be selected as duplicated.
please let me know if I need to provide more info.

Comment: How did you end up with duplicate payments in the first place?

Comment: Integrate with your first try then we will help you

Comment: thank you Ed Heal, I want to check if we have duplicated payment due to bugs in the App which generates all the starts_on and ends_on data and we charge customer accordingly

Comment: thank you  @theOni, I couldn't find a way to sort it out so, I did this to see if there is any duplicated payment in the last month                                                SELECT customer_id,count(id) payment, starts_on,period_type,state FROM payments
where starts_on between (current_date()- interval 1 month) and current_date()
and ends_on between (current_date()- interval 1 month) and current_date()
group by customer_id
having count(id) > 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, try it and we'll fix if it don't cover every case:

```
SELECT customer_id,
       id,
       starts_on,
       period_type,
       state
FROM payments p
WHERE     state = 'invested'
      AND EXISTS
             (SELECT 1
              FROM payments
              WHERE     state != 'refunded'
                    AND customer_id = p.customer_id
                    AND id != p.id
                    AND (   (    starts_on <= p.starts_on
                             AND ends_on >= p.starts_on)
                         OR (starts_on <= p.ends_on AND ends_on >= p.ends_on)))
```